# ArcGIS Qt - back_button how to disable on Android

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-runtime

I'm developing Qt/QML application

It seems that "back button" is handled by ArcGIS Runtime for Android

As soon as I add qml runtime to my pro file:

```
include(/opt/arcgis/runtime_sdk/qt100.2.1/sdk/ideintegration/arcgis_runtime_qml.pri)
```

I have no control over back button on android.

I'm using V-Play framework which is handling back button, but when I create app with arcgis_runtime_qml.pri back button closes the app immediatelly.

How to disable back button handling by ArcGIS ?

Best Regards

Marek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get control over back button on android you just have to add on your main qml file this:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

ApplicationWindow {
    onClosing:{
        // handle back button
        close.accepted = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, Muchas gracias seniore ;)